# нужно составить алгоритм

Tags: python

Алгоритм возведения любого целого положительного числа в любую
целую положительную степень, не используя стандартные функции
языка программирования

Comment: используйте двоичный поиск

Comment: Вы сами умеете возвести 3^8? Как вы это делаете? Программу написать сможете?

Comment: @tym32167, не двоичный поиск а быстрое возведение в степень? Думаю что ТС пока не до таких тонкостей.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, забыл название. Ну нет так нет )

Answer (score 1):

Это довольно просто!

С помощью **int** и **input** вводим любое целое число и степень.
После чего с помощью **if** проверяем является ли число и степень положительными. И если они таковыми являются - возводим число в степень и выводим ответ.

```
a = int(input("Введите число: "))

if a > 0:
    n = int(input("Введите степень: "))
    if n > 0:
        c = a**n
        print("Ответ: ", c)
    else:
        print("Степень не является положительной.")
else:
    print("Число не является положительным.")
```

Comment: `a ** n` - это стандартная для питона операция возведения в степень, а в вопросе указано: `не используя стандартные функции языка программирования`

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос очень простой, достаточно вспомнить, что такое [возведение в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).

```py
def my_pow(a: int, n: int) -> int:
    res = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        res *= a
    return res
```

Также есть простой и не сложный алгоритм, который предлагали в комментариях под этим вопросом: алгоритм [бинарного возведения в степень](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow). Вот одна из его реализаций:

```py
def binpow(a: int, n: int) -> int:
    res = 1
    while n:
        if n & 1:
            res *= a
        a *= a
        n >>= 1
    return res
```